# How to show that A is countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the set $A$= $\{f:[1, \ldots, n] \rightarrow [1, \ldots, n]:  $f$ \text{ is a bijective function } \}$is a countable set.

How am I supposed to show things like this one?

Comment: What exactly is $A$? A set with a single bijective function? The set of all bijective functions from $[1...n]$ to itself? The set of all bijective functions from $[1...n]$ to itself for each natural $n$? In any case, you should be able to prove that it is countable by showing that you can order them in a list, one by one, preferably in stone systematic manner.

Comment: A is the set of al bijective functions from [1..n] to itself for each natural n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_n = \{ f: [1, \ldots, n] \to [1, \ldots, n] : f \text{ is a bijection}\}$

There are a total of $n!$ bijections from $[1, \ldots, n]$ to $[1, \ldots, n]$.

Since it is finite, $A_n$ must be countable.

Also, $\bigcup A_n$ is also countable.

Comment: Apparently, it's not just a single $n$, but for each natural number $n$ (see the comments below the question). This means it's not for any more.

Comment: I see, let me edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you don't know how to characterize the bijective functions as permutations of $\{1,2,..,n\}$ you can still achieve the result by counting only the functions.

There are $n^n$ of them so the set is finite. (for $f(1)$ there are $n$ possible values, for $f(2)$ idem, and so on).

The set of bijections is obviously included in this one, so it has to be finite too for every $n$.